# adding boolean column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

with this code i want to create boolean column `check` to check if the value in the column `LTP` is in the range of 0.10% of column `val`.

all values are of type `float`.

```
   df = df.assign(upper_range=lambda x: (x['val'] +(x['val'] * 0.001)))
   df = df.assign(lower_range=lambda x: ( x['val']- (x['val'] * 0.001) ) )
   df = df.assign(check=lambda x: (x['LTP'] >= x['lower_range'] & x['LTP'] <= x['upper_range']))
```

this code gave error

```
    TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, 
    and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule 
    ''safe''

    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'float'
```

for comparison i also tried using `and` instead of `&`
for which following error occured

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not closed `()` correctly, need parantheses for each condition:

```
 df = df.assign(check=lambda x: (x['LTP'] >= x['lower_range']) & (x['LTP'] <= x['upper_range']))
```

Comment: @user4599 - Unfortunately no experiece with `flask`, so cannot help you.